# Is the data traffic between EC2 and Lightsail free (in EC2 billing)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I looked at the pricing pages for both EC2 and Lightsail but could not find anything.

I am more concerned about data bills on EC2 side as EC2 data is much more expensive.

I can relocate servers to be in the same region if that helps reduce cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data between Regions is definitely charged at full Data Transfer prices.

Data within the same Region but in different AZs would be charged at 1c/GB (possibly 2c/GB since it might be charged from both ends).

The lowest-cost option would be to **establish VPC Peering** between Lightsail and your VPC, and having the resources in the same AZ. This should (?) eliminate any Data Transfer charge.

This might be helpful: [Understanding Data Transfer in AWS - The Duckbill Group](https://www.duckbillgroup.com/blog/understanding-data-transfer-in-aws/)